# gstreamer elements not present in nuitka compiled application

Tags: python, gstreamer, nuitka

i created an application using nuitka in a conda environment. i installed gstreamer in the following way in the conda env.

1: intsall gstreamer base
conda install -c anaconda gstreamer
conda install PyGObject

2: download the respective gstreamer msi package match the version in this case 1.22.4

link: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/

download MSVC 64-bit (VS 2019, Release CRT)

two files
a. 1.22.4 runtime installer
b. 1.22.4 development installer

3. install both the files in order file a follwed by file b

by default it gets installed in C:\gstreamer

4. copy the gstreamer to conda env

reason: certain elements where missing in gstreamer

copy all files in the path C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64 to path %userprofile%\miniconda3\Library

then used nuitka to compile my python code as exe app in standalone mode.

i get error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_property'.

for line second line below:
videosrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("mfvideosrc", "videosrc")
videosrc.set_property("device-index",device_number)

i check the compiled code, it had missing dll and other files. No gstreamer file and gi folder existed. i tried copying the missing dll into the folder no luck.

I feel either i got gstreamer installed wrong or i need to follow a specific step to add additional missing files to fix the gstreamer.

any tip or advice is welcome.